# Asp.net Core MVC application with Angular Kendo UI

Tags: angular

`Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:7398/app
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:7398/app
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:7398/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1069:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:7398/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:7398/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:47)
        at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:7398/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:498:34)
        at invokeTask (http://localhost:7398/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1364:14)
        at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:7398/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1382:17)
    Error loading http://localhost:7398/app
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:7398/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1069:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:7398/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:7398/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:47)
        at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:7398/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:498:34)
        at invokeTask (http://localhost:7398/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1364:14)
        at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:7398/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1382:17)
    Error loading http://localhost:7398/app`
Can anyone help me out to resolve this error, I have been trying to resolve this issue for hrs

Always getting below message:

> http://localhost:7398/app 404 (Not Found)

Here I am trying to integrate KendoUI for angular with Aspnet core web application##

```js
Here is my System.config.js

/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': './app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'cldr-data': 'npm:cldr-data',
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'jszip': 'npm:jszip',
      'systemjs-plugin-json': 'npm:systemjs-plugin-json',
      'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js',

      // Kendo UI for Angular scopes
      '@progress': 'npm:@progress',
      '@telerik': 'npm:@telerik'
    },
    meta: {
      '*.json': {
        loader: 'systemjs-plugin-json'
      }
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },

      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      jszip: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        main: './dist/jszip.js'
      },

      'systemjs-plugin-json': {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          main: 'json.js'
      },

      // Kendo UI for Angular packages
      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-buttons': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-charts': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-dialog': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-grid': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-inputs': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-intl': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-l10n': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-layout': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-sortable': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-popup': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-upload': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-charts': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-data-query': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-date-math': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-drawing': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-file-saver': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-intl': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-ooxml': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@progress/kendo-popup-common': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@telerik/kendo-draggable': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@telerik/kendo-dropdowns-common': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@telerik/kendo-intl': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'npm:@telerik/kendo-inputs-common': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);




Here is my tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "rootDir": "app",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app"
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot/node_modules",
    "node_modules"
  ],

  "compileOnSave": true
}

package.json


{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.32.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "systemjs-plugin-json": "0.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew8iG.png)Can anyone help me out to resolve this error, I have been trying to resolve this issue for hrs

Here I am trying to integrate kendo ui for angular with aspnet core web application

```html
Layout.cshtml

<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="~/js/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
   
    
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you post the complete error ?

Comment: found the link for the error snapshot . Have you set the ``<base href="/"> `` in your ``index.html`` ?

Comment: I tried by setting base in my index.html but it didn't work

Comment: change your ``app : './app'`` to ``app: 'app'`` in systemjs.config.js .

Comment: appreciate your response, previously it was app : 'app' only but i was getting same issues so i tried ./app